# How to open new activity every time i click the notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Say, I have got 5 notification for an app. Now my application is in closed state. If i click on one notification, the application is opening the needed activity. But How to make the notification to open the new activity every time i click the notification even the app is open.

The app has a splash screen and the needed activity is the third child of splash screen.

I have implemented as follows :
On clicking notification will launch the splash screen with some boolean set if it comes from notification. I am opening the need activity from the splash screen according to the boolean.

If i click the notification when the app is already open, it again starts from the splash screen.

How to implement opening a activity from notification as it happens in whats app.

Comment: Why not open the needed activity directly instead of going through the splash screen first?

Comment: need to check whether the token is valid or not. I do that in splash screen. If the token is valid ill open the feed for the notification.

Comment: you mean pending intents?